# Limits within determinants of Increasingly large matricies

Tags: matrices

Consider an n*n Matrix called A, where the elements within A are either 1 or 0. As n approaches Infinity, What percent of the possible matrices have det(A)=0?

Comment: As a start, it is easier to consider the percentage of matrices that have an *even* determinant; of course if this percent is zero then you have your answer.

Comment: In terms of $n$, that answer happens to be 
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n(1 - 2^{-k}) \approx 0.28879
$$
which, notably, is not zero.

Comment: It's because the probability that 2 row's are the same decrease exponentially as more rows/columns are added.

Comment: But the number of rows/columns increase linearly.

Comment: Actually, my answer above should have been $1 - 0.28879$, which is perhaps surprisingly high.

Comment: Related (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18547/number-of-unique-determinants-for-an-nxn-0-1-matrix) (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/01-Matrix.html).